React Native Firebase - on iOS onMessage event is not firing in Foreground
This question was submitted in GitHub issues here - reposting with a hope to save time for others running into the same problem
Trying to change the push notifications package used by an old app to the latest React Native and Firebase messaging. I have set up a new app from scratch to isolate the issue - all new identifiers, bundle ids, certificates, etc. The only things installed in the new project are yarn add @react-native-firebase/app and @react-native-firebase/messaging
On Android everything works. On iOS background and killed state messages are also working, but onMessage event is never fired when in Foreground 
I followed all the latest guides on https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup , https://rnfirebase.io/ , https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage and https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage/ios-setup.
I am sending the notifications with AWS SNS.

With help of great people responding to my GitHub issue, I was able to get this to work.
Thank you so much guys, it is now working 
The onMessage function worked correctly when notifications were sent from the Firebase console, but our backend uses AWS SNS, and switching to using Firebase REST API would be too complicated.
Investigating further, I found useful discussions in old GitHub issues (e.g. #3479 and #5908) addressing problems with the gcm.message_id key.
Rather than altering the code in RNFBMessaging+UNUserNotificationCenter.m by removing the if (notification.request.content.userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]) condition (which risks being overwritten during updates), I opted to add a dummy gcm.message_id to the payload. This solution proved to be effective.
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": {
      "title": "Sample Title",
      "body": "Sample Message"
    }
  },
  "url": "https://example.com",
  "gcm.message_id": "123"
}

